# Float converted to infinity in mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, mobile, safari, frontend

The var transX is converted to infinity when executed in mobile Safari and Chrome, it outputs the correct value on desktop.

```
var transX = (((((window.outerWidth/2) - ((element.offsetLeft) + (element.offsetWidth/2)))/(window.outerWidth/2))/2)*300);
```

I've tried parseInt() and .toFixed(x) but it won't output the actual value, just converts to infinity every time.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mobile Safari was returning 0 for window.outerWidth.

A number divided by 0 is converted to Infinity.

Using window.innerWidth instead.